# Finding the 20 most commented 20 news

Tags: sql

I need to find a function. the scenario is :
I have 2 table. 1. news table 2. news_comment table

need to find the most commented 20 news.
the news_comment table has the relationship with the news table

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the give query. it may help.

Top 20 give first 20,
join lin 2 tables
count(news_comment.id) give no of comment

```
select top 20 news.*, count(news_comment.id) as no_of_comment from news inner join news_comment on news.id = news_comment.newsid order by no_of_comment desc
```

Comment: Possibly a GROUP BY needed.  Which DB engine are you working with?  Just adapt the given query.

Comment: for mysql: select a.id, a.title, count(b.id) no_of_comment from news a inner join news_comment b on a.id = b.news_id group by a.id, a.title order by no_of_comment limit 0,20